# How do i find a use the drive SDK to find a file using only drive.file scope

Tags: google-drive-api

My scenario is that I want to look for a file, that if it exists, was created by my app.

If I request drive scope, I can use

```
/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse+and+title+%3D+'MyFile'+and+'root'+in+parents
```

and all is good.

But this requires access to all the users existing drive files, which is too demanding.
So I removed the **drive** scope and try the same command with only **drive.file** scope.

In return I get

```
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
```

Hacking around, if I remove the 'root' in parents, I get

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "\"Q5ElJByAJoL0etObruYVPRipH1k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse+and+title+%3D+'MyFile'",
 "items": []
}
```

which is better than a 500, but still not what I expected.

So how can I check if MyFile exists without requiring **drive** scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug we're fixing soon.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/children?q=title+contains+'My title'
```

will also only list files from `root` that your application has right to access.

Comment: That works, thx Burcu. Having leapt that hurdle, I've now hit another scope issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246001/what-scope-is-required-to-read-an-uploaded-file :-(