# What scope is required to read an uploaded file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am uploading a file to Drive using the JS client, then trying to access that file from my server app by downloading its content. The server code is ...

```
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
```

This works fine if the user has granted the all **drive** scope. However if the user only grants **drive.file**, the call fails with a 404 error.

If I look at the uploaded file using the Drive web page, it shows as being created by my app.

What do I need to do to read my uploaded file without **drive** scope?

My picker code is ...

```
tools.Constants.clientId = '694357857995';

var picker = new `google.picker.PickerBuilder()
.setAuthUser(cnU['email'])
.addView(uploadView)
.addView(view)
.setAppId(tools.Constants.clientId)
.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
.setCallback($scope.pickerCallback2)
.build();`
```

Comment: drive.file should let you access file your app has created. Could you provide minimum code and procedure to reproduce this?

Comment: The server code is above. I've edited the question to also include the picker code. I've read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119557/getting-google-file-picker-to-work-with-drive-file-scope and have double checked that I am using the shortest form of client id.